# Match string and one or more numbers with grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I've got a file `myfile`. I want to find lines that includes following pattern:

```
MyWebsite/1234
```

or more general

**somecharactersstringswhitespaces**MyWebsite/987**somecharactersstringswhitespaces**

There can be 1 or more numbers after `MyWebsite`.
I have tried following:

```
grep ".*MyWebsite[0-9]\{1,\}" myfile
grep "MyWebsite[0-9]\{1,\}" myfile
grep MyWebsite"[0-9]\{1,\}" myfile
grep -E ".*MyWebsite/[0-9]\{1,\}.*" myfile
```

None of them worked, even if intuition and logic says that should be good.

Comment: There are weird versions of `grep` in some OSes (especially old ones). Try `grep "MyWebsite[0-9][0-9]*" myfile`. Note that when you use `-E`, you should not escape the limiting quantifier.

Comment: Ah, you have `/` there, so try `grep "MyWebsite/[0-9][0-9]*" myfile`. or maybe with `/`, some of your patterns may work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep 'MyWebsite/[0-9]\+' myfile` should work. On your first 3 regexes, you missed the `/` and on the last, you shouldn't have escaped the `{` and `}`, but otherwise you were pretty good. It's more concise to use `+` rather than `{1,}` though, and the version of regex that grep uses by default (a variant of POSIX BRE) requires it to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

## Setup

> grep (GNU grep) 3.7

## Solution

```bash
grep 'MyWebsite/[[:digit:]]\+' myfile
```

### Breakdown

- `[[:digit:]]` character class that matches digits 0..9
- `\` escape character
- `+` match one or more characters (digits in this case)

## Prove

```bash
# create myfile with content 'a bc/MyWebsite/1234/d ef'
echo 'a bc/MyWebsite/1234/d ef' > myfile

# test grep
grep 'MyWebsite/[[:digit:]]\+' myfile

# remove myfile
rm myfile
```

### Result

> a bc/MyWebsite/1234/d ef

### Highlighted pattern match

[image]

## Links

- [grep Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)